# Unrecognized option: -d64 occurs with IBM Informix installation

Tags: java, ibm-server

Following error is occurring when I'm trying to install IBM informix **ids.12.10.FC12TL.macosx64.dmg** in my MacBook (Runs HighSierra)

**Error while trying to install IBM Informix**

```
Last login: Sat Oct 27 22:15:35 on ttys000
/Volumes/ids.12.10.FC12TL.macosx64/ids_install ; exit;
Macbooks-MacBook-Pro:~ isharakularatna$ /Volumes/ids.12.10.FC12TL.macosx64/ids_install ; exit;
Preparing to install...
Extracting the installation resources from the installer archive...
Configuring the installer for this system's environment...

Launching installer...

Unrecognized option: -d64
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Also I checked the java version and whether the java compiler is working with `javac` command, it shows both are working fine, Appreciate your help to resolve this issue.

**Result of java -version**

```
Macbooks-MacBook-Pro:~ isharakularatna$ java -version
java version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13, mixed mode)
Macbooks-MacBook-Pro:~ isharakularatna$
```

Answer (score 2):

The `d64` flag is obsolete and doesn't work any more starting with JDK-10.
It is marked as deprecated in JDK-9 but still functions.
The current version is already JDK-11.

For more information see the article
[Obsolete java options -d32, -d64 in jdk-10 affect scripts domain.sh, standalone.sh, appclient.sh](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-10448?_sscc=t).

You need to either get a newer version of IBM Informix (if available)
or go down in JDK versions.

The curious point here is that
[d64 is said to apply only to Solaris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31078803/usage-of-d32-and-d64-while-launching-java),
which is an additional reason to verify your Informix version.

Comment: I will try with downgrading my JDK version, but this installation came with .dmg format which supports to MacOS X installations. Also it was provided from official IBM - Informix web site. I will check and post if the status

Comment: Still same result after downgrading to JDK8 / JRE 8, are there any other suggestions

Comment: Try the commands `java -d32 -version` and `java -d64 -version`. As long as they both not work, the Java version you have does not support that switch. IBM informix, [reported](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24009130) as last modified on August 4, 2014, may not be usable in your environment.

Comment: Yes you are correct, Both options did not work and gives an error as  "Unrecognized option: -d64 Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit."

Comment: I don't know for which combination of OSX/Java was created that dmg, but it's certainly not advisable to adapt your system for it. There are other databases which are current, for example MySQL.

Comment: Yes, but this time I have to work with IBM informix since there is an urgent request. I was trying to simulate using my PC, I will try with linux distribution. Thanks for the help so far !

Comment: I suggest using a virtual machine, so as not to destroy your system. If this answer has helped in your problem, you might mark it as accepted.

Comment: Yes, Sure I will do as soon as possible, Thanks for following up !